# Unscramble string code in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, reverse-engineering

I have a function in Oracle SQL which scrambles a given input. I need to unscramble it.

I need a program which can basically reverse the output of the program below.

```
source IN VARCHAR2
sGARBLED VARCHAR2(510);
index NUMBER;
length NUMBER;
onec NUMBER;

BEGIN
    length := LENGTH(source);
    IF length > 255 THEN
    length := 255;
      END IF;
 index := 1;
 sGARBLED := '';

 WHILE index <= length LOOP
    onec := ASCII(SUBSTR(source, index, 1)) - 30;
    IF (onec < 10) THEN
        sGARBLED := sGARBLED || '0';    
    END IF;
    sGARBLED := sGARBLED || CAST(onec AS VARCHAR2);
    index := index + 1;
  END LOOP;

 RETURN sGARBLED;
END
```

Comment: It may not be possible.  It appears from your `IF (onec < 10)` you're attempting to make sure each input character creates two output characters.  However, it's possible for the input text to contain characters with ASCII values greater than 130, meaning they add three characters to the output string.
Without a guarantee that each input character maps to two output characters, there's not a deterministic way to unscramble it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be possible, if you are only allowing character values in your original string before scrambling it, to be characters of the alphabet.

Code would look something like this:

```
sgarbled in VARCHAR2 
UNsGARBLED VARCHAR2(255);

length NUMBER;
index NUMBER;
onec NUMBER;

BEGIN
length := LENGTH(sgarbled);
index := 1;
UNsGARBLED := '';

 WHILE index <= length LOOP
 onec := SUBSTR(sgarbled, index, 1);
    IF (onec = '0') THEN
        onec := SUBSTR(sgarbled, (index + 1), 1) + 30; 
    ELSE 
        onec := SUBSTR(sgarbled, (index), 2) + 30;
    END IF;
    UNsGARBLED := UNsGARBLED || CAST(CHR(onec) AS VARCHAR2);
    index := index + 2;
  END LOOP;

 RETURN UNsGARBLED;
END
```

As Mr. Llama pointed out if you are allowing the original input string to contain all ASCII characters then it may not be possible.

Comment: Thank you for the program. its very helpful. In the actual program, the source string is being converted to ASCII. how are we converting it back from ASCII.

Comment: Is the source string originally only allowed to be characters of the alphabet? or any other restrictions on characters of string?

Comment: You can use CHR() to convert ASCII value back to symbol it refers to.